# Replacing a pattern in line preceding another pattern of interest

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have a log file with many instances of statements as shown below:

```
14 Aug 19 16:30:11.506: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|01131844090|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
20 Aug 19 16:30:12.439: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|01131844090|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
21 ###############################################################################
```

I want to replace `IDLE` just preceding the `#########..` to say, `END` and have other cases of `IDLE` retained.

How do I achieve it?

Edit:
   Maybe something is different with my actual file. Answers to this question haven't met the requirement. Detailed extract and my requirement is shown below:

```
  22 Aug 19 16:47:33.159: <DATA>  |POS|RINGING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    23 Aug 19 16:47:33.453: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    24 Aug 19 16:47:33.484: <DATA>  |POS|TRAINING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    25 Aug 19 16:48:05.824: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    26 Aug 19 16:48:05.916: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    27 Aug 19 16:48:05.947: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    28 Aug 19 16:48:23.792: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    29 Aug 19 16:48:23.853: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    30 Aug 19 16:48:23.884: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
    31 ##############################################################################
```

After operating on the above instance, the result should be:
(`IDLE` preceding `####` line is changed to `END`.Note there are many instances of such events. My actual need is to find time diff between `RINGING` and `IDLE - aka END)`

```
22 Aug 19 16:47:33.159: <DATA>  |POS|RINGING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
23 Aug 19 16:47:33.453: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
24 Aug 19 16:47:33.484: <DATA>  |POS|TRAINING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
25 Aug 19 16:48:05.824: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
26 Aug 19 16:48:05.916: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
27 Aug 19 16:48:05.947: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
28 Aug 19 16:48:23.792: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
29 Aug 19 16:48:23.853: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
30 Aug 19 16:48:23.884: <DATA>  |POS|END|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
31 ##############################################################################
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: The `ex` command way will work only on the first matching line. The perl example will replace for all lines with the pattern, but will only give the output and not edit the origitnal file, so you will have to redirect the output to a new file. YOUR-LOGFILE should be replaced by the location of the file you are trying to modify.

> perl -0pe 's/IDLE(.*\n.*###)/END\1/g' YOUR-LOGFILE > NEWFILE

This will replace the line just above the line containing the pattern and then exit.

> ex -s +'/######/-1 s/IDLE/END/ | x' YOUR-LOGFILE

Comment: thanks. Yes. `ex` worked on the first instance. However, I see the perl script didn't meet the requirement either.

Comment: @Prabhu now you can use the `perl` script. Earlier there were some characters  missing due to the SE editor's features. I have updated my answer now.

Comment: Sure. I will do.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk '!/^#+$/ {print l; l=$0; next} {gsub("IDLE","END",l); print l; l=$0} END {print $0}' < log.txt
```

which gives:

```
Aug 19 16:30:11.506: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|01131844090|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
Aug 19 16:30:12.439: <DATA>  |POS|END|1|01131844090|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
###############################################################################
```

Comment: ,thanks. With my large set not all `IDLE` in line preceding the line containing `#####..` are replaced. But I see the line - `####..` getting duplicated above all occurrences of `#####..`.

Comment: @garethTheRed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: @Gnouc - Guilty as charged! I've edited.

Comment: Where did your log file come from? Is it correctly formatted as per your example?  I've expanded your example by duplicating lines and it still works.  Also, what about the newline characters? Is this from a Windows machine?

Comment: I have edited the questions adding more details. I copied the contents from my VI editor.

Comment: Apologies! I assumed only one instance of `######`.  I belive it's fixed now.

Comment: @garethTheRed,NP at all. The current solution didn't give the desired output. Replacement of `IDLE` to `END` didn't occur.

Comment: Are the line numbers part of the file?

Comment: No. Line numbers are not part of the file

Comment: Your file doesn't have Unix/Linux line endings.  Either run the log file through `dos2unix` first, or add `-v RS='\r\n'` just after the `awk` ( to make `awk -v RS='\r\n' '\[^.....`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - that was a typo when entering it in U&L. I'm using the complemented character list `[^#]+` here.  However, when I think about it, that's not very robust. I got away with it as there is no single `#` in the text lines.  I've edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '$!N;/###$/s/IDLE/END/;P;D
' <<\DATA
22 Aug 19 16:47:33.159: <DATA>  |POS|RINGING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
23 Aug 19 16:47:33.453: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
24 Aug 19 16:47:33.484: <DATA>  |POS|TRAINING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
25 Aug 19 16:48:05.824: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
26 Aug 19 16:48:05.916: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
27 Aug 19 16:48:05.947: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
28 Aug 19 16:48:23.792: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
29 Aug 19 16:48:23.853: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
30 Aug 19 16:48:23.884: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
31 ##############################################################################
DATA
```

That expands `sed`'s normal one-line buffer to a two-line buffer. On every line but the last it appends the next input line to pattern space. If the two-line buffer ends with the string  `###` it replaces the first occurring `IDLE` string with `END`. It then `P`rints up to the first occurring newline in the buffer and `D`eletes same before starting over with what remains. It's an extremely simple, POSIX-portable, and very fast solution to your problem.

#### OUTPUT

```
22 Aug 19 16:47:33.159: <DATA>  |POS|RINGING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
23 Aug 19 16:47:33.453: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
24 Aug 19 16:47:33.484: <DATA>  |POS|TRAINING|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
25 Aug 19 16:48:05.824: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
26 Aug 19 16:48:05.916: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
27 Aug 19 16:48:05.947: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
28 Aug 19 16:48:23.792: <DATA>  |POS|IDLE|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
29 Aug 19 16:48:23.853: <DATA>  |POS|INIT|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
30 Aug 19 16:48:23.884: <DATA>  |POS|END|1|1126710938|5950|$hostIp|$size  |$data
31 ##############################################################################
```

To edit a file in-place portably you can do:

```
 sed '$!N;/###$/s/IDLE/END/;P;D
 ' <<FILE >file
 $(cat file)
 FILE
```

Or else, with GNU `sed` at least you might do:

```
 sed -i '$!N;/###$/s/IDLE/END/;P;D' file
```